How do I stop my stm32 from halting my code when it gets it?
I recently got an stm32 board, and right now I am just trying to establish communication with it by turning on the LD2 light, using platformio. Right now when I try to upload the code the board seems that it is immediately halted, giving a warning message and yellow that I will leave below.
I found this thread that says the issue is that I needed to include a debugger with my program so I added the line
debug_tool = stlink
to my platformio.ini file, but the problem persists. I pictures and text for what I think is relevant below but if there is anything else needed let me know and I will try and add it to the post.
my platformio.ini
the output message
the memory address the output is calling
The code
#include <libopencm3/stm32/rcc.h>
#include <libopencm3/stm32/gpio.h>

#define LED_PORT (GPIOA)
#define LED_PIN (GPIO6)


static void rcc_setup(void){
    rcc_clock_setup_pll(&rcc_hsi_configs[RCC_CLOCK_3V3_84MHZ]);

}

static void gpio_setup(void){
    rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_GPIOA);
    gpio_mode_setup(LED_PORT, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT, GPIO_PUPD_NONE, LED_PIN);
}
static void delay_cycles(uint32_t cycles){
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < cycles; i++){
        __asm__("nop");
    }

}

int main(void){
    rcc_setup();
    gpio_setup();
    gpio_toggle(LED_PORT, LED_PIN);
    while(true){
        delay_cycles(8400000 / 4);
    }

    return 0;
}


Don't post pictures of text.  Copy and paste the test in plaintext markdown.

I see no evidence that the link you posted relates to your issue.  I also see no advice to "include a debugger" whatever that might mean. Certainly however you should use a debugger.  ST-Link is debug hardware, but not itself a debugger - that is a software component such as GDB.

From what you posted, it seems to be there is no problem at all and this is all normal? I mean, you try to upload the code, so the debugger halts the CPU and uploads the code. What exactly about all of this is not normal?

Is this simply the initial breakpoint at main that you are experiencing?  This debug_init_break documentation page says the default behavior is to have a temporary breakpoint at main.  And you can disable the initial breakpoint by adding this line to the platformio.ini file.
; Examples 1: disable initial breakpoint
debug_init_break =

